# Questions about the pricing policy of the supabase - are API calls and Egress different?

Tags: supabase

I am developing an app using Supabase. They said, "API call is unlimited free." But according to the price policy, there is an additional charge according to Egress. If the number of API requests increases, doesn't Egress also increase?

I implemented the service by polling data from the database every 5 seconds. I did it because the API call was unlimited free, but I'm confused because there's an additional fee according to Egress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Supabase does not charge you based on how many API calls you make, but you get charged on egress.

Instead of polling your database, have you considered using Supabase Realtime? You can save a lot on egress that way, because the server only sends data when there are actually updates.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/realtime/postgres-changes